# newman CLI returns "error: unable to get local issuer certificate" in teamcity build

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, teamcity, newman

Using the newman nodeJS CLI to run a collection of postman test I get the following error:

> error: unable to get local issuer certificate

It is run as part of a Teamcity CI build using the following command:

```
newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/<COLLECTION-ID-HERE>
```

It is run on windows and we have a corporate proxy server (ZScaler).

How to I get newman to work?

Comment: the lazy and dirty solution : ```npm config set strict-ssl false```

Comment: Lazy, dirty, and insecure as it opens all your NodeJS apps up to man in the middle SSL attacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that newman cannot find (or does not know about) the self signed SSL certificate used by the proxy server that is configured in the windows certificate store. The easiest way to make newman (and actually any recent nodeJS app) aware of the certificate is to use an environment variable:

on windows:

```
SET NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=c:\some-folder\certificate.cer
```

on linux:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/c/some-folder/certificate.cer
```

You may also need to set the proxy server url itself with the `HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234` env varirable as well.

Alternatively the environment variables can be added to that teamcity builds runtime environment using the [build parameters feature of Teamcity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Configuring+Build+Parameters)

Note this is for Node.js 7.3.0 and above (and the LTS versions 6.10.0 and 4.8.0)

Comment: Ran into this on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance even though the company root CA was trusted by the OS. Setting the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` variable to point at the root cert indeed fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Just add --insecure in front of collectionID i.e  :

newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/?apiKey="your-Postman-Api-Key" --insecure

Also When triggering the execution using a json file, Just add --insecure So your command shall be :

newman run .postman_collection.json --insecure

Comment: This means your test suite will pass if there are any other SSL issues in your app, which is bad for security. Imagine your SSL cert was revoked because your ISP got hacked - it would be useful to find out when your automated nightly newman tests start failing? It is almost always better to fix the newman config with the correct certificate than just turning off all security using --insecure.